# Microsoft Publisher templates seem to have placeholder text. How to edit this?

Tags: ms-publisher

In Microsoft Publisher (2021 if that matters), templates usually display kind of placeholder data for the elements on a page. Text boxes have some text that may describe what the purpose of this box is.

[image]

*Screenshot of text box with "placeholder" text.*

I cannot place the cursor inside the text, just at the very start or very end. Clicking at any other position marks all text. Typing the replces that text completely.

[image]

*All the text box's "placeholder" text is selected when clicking inside*

[image]

*All "placeholder" text is replace by new text when typing*

It looks like that "placeholder" text block is kind of write protected.

How can I change that placeholder text, so that a new text is show when this is saved as a new template? I had no luck searching the internet, probably because I didn't use the right keywords.